# In Android Studio, Click on the text color with hotkey "Ctrl+B" got "cannot find declaration to go" error

Tags: android

[image]

`colors.xml` is in the folder `res/values/` which contains

```
<color name="offer_cell_price_bkg">#80000000</color>
```

But the android studio can not find it. I cleaned the project, relaunched the android studio and rebuilt the project, but still not work. Could you give me some suggestion? Thanks!

PS:I added my colors.xml file(It is a normal xml file, nothing special)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- item image -->
    <color name="image_without_palette">#1C1D23</color>
    <color name="text_without_palette">#ffeae1da</color>

</resources>
```

I tried to find other values like String and Dimen. I can find them.
The strange thing is: I can find colors in other xml like styles.xml. But can not find the colors in all fragment layout...

```html
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
                  <com.rey.material.widget.Slider
                    android:id="@+id/distance_range_slider"
                    style="@style/Material.Widget.Slider.Discrete"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:sl_primaryColor="@color/my_color_1"
                    app:sl_stepValue="1"
                    app:sl_textSize="0sp"
                    app:sl_value="20"/>
        <com.easydinner.utils.Widgets.RalewaySemiBoldTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/services"
            android:textColor="@color/my_color_2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font24"/>
  
  </LinearLayout>
```

In the same fragment layout, I can find the color of namespace "app", but not the "android". For example, I can find "my_color_1", but not "my_color_2"
Really don't know the reason.

Comment: Could you post your `colors.xml` file ? Are you able to use other `color` defined in your `colors.xml` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by updating my android studio to version 1.5, and SDK platform tool to version 23.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```